# False positive in duplicate diagnosis?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I hope that the meta mi yodea is the right place for this.
I noticed that a question, [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69470/how-do-rabbis-deal-with-meshaloch-manos-in-terms-of-kedushin), is considered as duplicate. That is not my question (bu *I am Nogea Badavar* because I tried to answer this question). It seems that an error occured because it is obviously not a duplicate, the subject is treated in two part in tosfot Nazir and gittin.
I have send a comment to say it but no response was given. I wondering, perhaps is that the rule, no discussion after decision? If it is the case, I can try to understand.
May be also that I do not see the duplication.
 But a good response is welcome.

1. A girl, Sarah do not know if his father married his daughter (Sarah) when she was younger than 12. Someone offer a gift and we have a doubt (Sivlonot topic, See the explanation of Rashi and Tosfot in massechet Kidushin 50B). See the explanation of the problem [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68940/how-can-a-man-give-a-woman-a-gift-without-getting-himself-into-a-safek-kiddushin).
2. We know that the above-cited problem exists. A man looks for a women to be his bread. He asks if there is uncertainty about every women because, perhaps she received mishloach manot as child, and if it is the case, her deceased father can not raise the doubt about kidushin.

The second case is the deleted question.

Comment: Meta is the right place to bring concerns like this.  Thank you for doing so!  And no, we definitely don't have a "no discussion after closure" rule; we're all human, and if you disagree with a decision about a particular question please *do* bring it up.  In this case I think the distinction between the two questions isn't clear to people; feel free to edit the one that's on hold to clarify the difference.  (I'm commenting rather than answering because I don't yet have an opinion on this question itself; I'm just responding to the "process" part of your question.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio I understand, I agree that the second topic is not a real good question but I realy think that it was the question. I matter of Chashat it is weak, but this denote the need to know the second sugia. Thanks for your post

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the two questions are asking basically the same thing. How can a man avoid getting into an issue with kiddushin when sending a woman a gift? The example in the newer question is slightly more specific, but it's the same thing. It could be that you have two different sources for this type of question. That sounds kind of normal.

Could you maybe explain why you think it's not a duplicate?

Comment: for the orphan girl toward all men, for everybody toward all girls. See please the tosfot itn nazir that I tried to explain

Comment: I explained in details the difference.

Comment: explained in the OP I hope that it is the original meaning of the Dude's  question.